# Trying to put classes in hashmap but its not working

Tags: java, class, hashmap

So i have input like this:

```
 [1]     name1 + type1 + value1
 [X]     nameX + typeX + valueX
```

now i am looking at input like this:

```
 [2]     name1 + type2 + value2
```

so [2] has same name as [1] but their properites are different.

i put the name,type,value in a class like this:

```
 class entity(){

 String name;
 String type;
 int amount;
 //constructor ... etc...
 ...
 }
```

what i want to do is put entity into a hashmap with the key being the name and the value being the class entity.

like this

```
  name1 ----> entity1
  nameX -----> entityX
```

the problem i am having is when i try to put [2] into the hashmap it has the same name as [1] so it doesnt hash properly ([2] overrides [1] since they have the same name.

i will need to later access [1] and [2] by their name when i search for it..
how would i enter it into the map so it wont override it.

Comment: If keys are not unique, there is no point of using hashmap.

Comment: @NafisIslam what would you suggest to use? i will need to search up the class using the name?

Comment: If [1] and [2] have the same name how do you distinguish this 2?

Comment: @NafisIslam i think SSP has got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You need to modify your class entity like below :-

```
 class entity(){

 String name;
 ArrayList <String> type;
 ArrayList <Integer> amount;
 //constructor ... etc...
 ...
 }
```

2 - Now when ever you are going to enter any value in hashmap, First check that is that key is available in map. If key is available in map, fetch that value associated to that key and enter your new type and amount value in arraylist.

```
if(hashmap.contains(nameX)){
    entity obj = hashmap.get(nameX);
    type.add(new_val);
    amount.add(new_val);
    hashmap.put(nameX,obj);
}
else{
    entity obj = new entity();
    type.add(new_val);
    amount.add(new_val);
    hashmap.put(nameX,obj);
}
```

Note:- change your class name from entity to Entity. its standards code pratice.

Comment: for any question comment here

Comment: ill try this and see if it works in my code... that entity was just a simple explanation of my problem so i wrote it on the spot

Comment: that's all right. I just wanted you to know that, its not the correct way to write a class name.

Comment: just finished my looong program and this worked... thank you.